# How to separate JSON pairs and store in sqlite database in android?

Tags: java, android, sql, json, sqlite

like if i have JSON :

```
{"Sugar":"sweet","salt":"salty","chilly":"hot"}
```

and i want to put the key in separate column and value in separate column in database.like shown in image below. is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the json1 extension installed, you can just use [table-valued function `json_each()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jeach) for this. It does exactly what you ask for, that is generate one row per json element, with the key in the first column and the value in the second column.

```
insert into mytable(ingredients, taste)
select * from json_each('{"Sugar":"sweet","salt":"salty","chilly":"hot"}')
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add the following maven dependency

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Then,

```
//Creating a JSONParser object
      JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
      try {
         //Parsing the contents of the JSON file
         JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("/path/to/json_file"));
         //Forming URL
         System.out.println("Contents of the JSON are: ");
         System.out.println(jsonObject.get("Sugar"));
         System.out.println(jsonObject.get("Salt"));
}
```

This way you can insert the keys in one column and values in another. You can use array indexes for the key.